# `virtualenv` doesn't work for Python2.x

Tags: python, virtualenv

Whenever I made a project, I always use `virtualenv` for developing environment(Python3.x). In this time, I tried to set environment as Python2.x but doesn't work. Here is what I did:
(Mac OS Yosemitie, virtualenv version 14.0.1, python3 version 3.5.1, python2 version 2.7.10)

```
$ cd `certain empty directory`
$ virtualenv --python=python2.7 venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I don't see why python version is 3.5.1.
When I type,

```
(venv)$ which python
/Users/Chois/Desktop/Programming/Project/chois_pystagram/venv/bin/python
(venv)$ cd /Users/Chois/Desktop/Programming/Project/chois_pystagram/venv/bin
(venv)$ ls
activate         activate_this.py pip              python           python2.7
activate.csh     easy_install     pip2             python-config    wheel
activate.fish    easy_install-2.7 pip2.7           python2
```

All `python` are version 2.7

How can I solve it?

Comment: what does `ẁhich python` show after sourcing venv?

Comment: I just checked whether `python` indicate `system-installed python` or `virtualenv python`.

Comment: Please do a `ls -la $(which python)` and show output here...

Comment: Why not just use `virtualenvwrapper`?